# Regex to extract specific field with other constraints

Tags: regex

I have to create a Regex which extract specific field from large log file. I have created one but its not perfect as different type of occurane present in logs.

I have attached screenshot. There are 2 different type of log entry and I want to extract real="value".

The problem is, multiple "real=value" present in extracted line and I want to get only first occurance. +

My Regex:

```
CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:\s.*real=(?P<cms_abortable_preclean>\d+\.\d+)\s
```

[Screen Shot: Sample data and Regex command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE0NY.jpg)

Sample Data:

> 2017-05-16T13:21:47.420+0200: 5.114: [GC (Allocation Failure)
>   2017-05-16T13:21:47.420+0200: 5.114:
>   [ParNew2017-05-16T13:21:47.461+0200: 5.155:
>   [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.120/0.735 secs] [Times:
>   user=1.17 sys=0.12, real=**0.73** secs] : 886080K->110720K(996800K),
>   0.3158400 secs] 886080K->161751K(6180736K), 0.3168208 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.10, real=0.32 secs]
>
> 1.583: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.052/0.171 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.01, real=**0.17** secs]  CMS: abort preclean due to time
>   8077.162: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 4.850/5.566 secs] [Times: user=5.92 sys=0.02, real=5.57 secs]

I want to extract fields in **bold**.

Comment: @k-five : sorry i didn't specify before that i dont want language specific. its for splunk tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
^.*?Times.*?real=(\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z52wgL/1)**

The idea is to capture the first `real` belonging to `Times` for each line

Comment: Thanks!! Its almost done. the only issue is i have to match "CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:" string as well. for first log type its working fine for second type its extracting both the occurance. Its small correction which i am missing. Could you please help.

Comment: I am trying to mark it close but not be able to do so. I am not getting any option to mark it close.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
(CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:).*?(?=.*:)(?<=real=)(\d+\.\d+)
```

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z52wgL/3)

The first group match: `CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:`
And the second is: `(\d+\.\d+)`

---

Fast test:

```
perl -lne 'print "$1 and $2" while/(CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:).*?(?=.*:)(?<=real=)(\d+\.\d+)/g;' file
```

the output:

```
CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: and 0.73
CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: and 0.17
```